# Android Button onClickListener throws a null exception

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am having trouble setting an `onclicklistener` for my `Buttons`.  While some of them are working properly, others are not working.  The code shows no errors but when i run the app i am presented with errors in the `Log`, one of which says `NullPointerException` button instead of an anonymous one, but that tells me that the void `onClick()` is not a valid type for variable.  I have tried setting the XML code for the `Button` to call the `onClick()` defined in the code, but that also throws an error on runtime.  I have also tried declaring the `onClick()` outside of the `onCreate()` but that also throws an error at runtime.  The button that is not working is homeb01.  I am stuck, my code is below and i could really use some help.  Thank you.

```
package com.example.deenbuddy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

MainActivity context;

//Arrays for RowItem values
final Integer[] uname = new Integer[] {R.string.temp_uname0,R.string.temp_uname0,R.string.temp_uname0,R.string.temp_uname0};
final Integer[] ustatus = new Integer[]{R.string.temp_ustatus0,R.string.temp_ustatus0,R.string.temp_ustatus0,R.string.temp_ustatus0};
final Integer[] upic = new Integer[]{R.drawable.tig0,R.drawable.tig0,R.drawable.tig0,R.drawable.tig0};

//ListView and RowItem for ListView
ListView listview;
List<RowItem> rowItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    //Navigation Buttons
    final Button homeb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_b0);
    final Button newsb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_b0);
    final Button featb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feature_b0);
    final Button homeb01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_b1);
    final Button newsb01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_b1);
    final Button featb01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feature_b1);

    //News Buttons 
    final ImageView newsb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news1);
    final ImageView newsb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news2);
    final ImageView newsb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news3);
    final ImageView newsb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news4);

    //Feature Buttons
    final ImageView featb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat1);
    final ImageView featb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat2);
    final ImageView featb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat3);
    final ImageView featb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat4);

    //OnClicks



    //OnClick for Navigation
    //h_home
    homeb0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view2)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    });
    //f_home
```

the button that is not working is this one, homeb01

```
    homeb01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
    });

    //n_home
    //h_news
    newsb0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
        }
    });
    //h_feat
    featb0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.featurestitle);
        }
    });

    //OnClicks for news
    newsb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
        }
    });

    newsb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
        }
    });

    newsb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
        }
    });

    newsb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
        }
    });

    //OnClicks for feat
    featb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.featurestitle);
        }
    });

    featb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.featurestitle);
        }
    });

    featb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.featurestitle);
        }
    });

    featb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.featurestitle);
        }
    });



    rowItem = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for(int x = 0; x < uname.length; x++)
    {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(upic[x], uname[x], ustatus[x]);
        rowItem.add(item);
    }

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sfeed);
    CListView adapter = new CListView(this,R.layout.sfeed_list,rowItem);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}





}
```

My LogCat is as follows:

```
07-11 01:54:58.247: E/Trace(21487): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-11 01:54:59.833: D/AndroidRuntime(21487): Shutting down VM
07-11 01:54:59.833: W/dalvikvm(21487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x414252a0)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deenbuddy/com.example.deenbuddy.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at com.example.deenbuddy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    at     
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
07-11 01:54:59.942: E/AndroidRuntime(21487):    ... 11 more
07-11 01:55:02.856: I/Process(21487): Sending signal. PID: 21487 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Instead of calling `setContentView` multiple times, use a `ViewFlipper` or `FrameLayout`

Comment: i will look into this and let you know what happens, thank you

Comment: There is no code to be executed in the onClick() of your homeb01 button's onClickListener....

Comment: post the logcat please

Comment: Ok i have posted my logcat and updated the code, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
 //Navigation Buttons
    final Button homeb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_b0);
    final Button newsb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_b0);
    final Button featb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feature_b0);
    final Button homeb01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_b1);
    final Button newsb01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_b1);
    final Button featb01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feature_b1);

    //News Buttons 
    final ImageView newsb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news1);
    final ImageView newsb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news2);
    final ImageView newsb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news3);
    final ImageView newsb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news4);

    //Feature Buttons
    final ImageView featb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat1);
    final ImageView featb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat2);
    final ImageView featb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat3);
    final ImageView featb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat4);

    //OnClicks
    homeb0.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsb0.setOnClickListener(this);
    featb0.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsb01.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeb01.setOnClickListener(this);
    featb01.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsb2.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsb3.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsb4.setOnClickListener(this);
    featb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    featb2.setOnClickListener(this);
    featb3.setOnClickListener(this);
    featb4.setOnClickListener(this);




  }
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
     switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.home_b0:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.newsb0:
        //Code
        break;

    case R.id.featb0:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.newsb01:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.homeb01:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.featb01:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.home_b0:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.newsb1:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.newsb2:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.newsb3:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.newsb4:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.featb1:
        //Code
        break;
    case R.id.featb2:
        //Code
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

and why setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); inside button click  event can you tell what exactly you wanna do

Comment: it is always better to create separate OnClickListener classes for each button rather than implementing the methods in your activity.

Comment: I set content view to my main_activity layout because if the user goes to a different page and wants to go back to the main paige the contentView must change

Comment: you can create separate class(ll prefer Fragment).sorry still i dont understand your logic .bcoz  you can pass a clss to an intent.by this you can com back to main class.

Comment: but i want to change layouts

should i make seperate classes for each layout?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your declaration of "home_b1" id in the xml is as below:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/home_b1"/>
```

Do not miss the "+" before id.